# i need to make that when my computer is plugged, it start automaticaly

Tags: 20.04

I use a computer for music and i use a Di-o to unplug him automaticaly when i do not want music anymore (he does not have a batterie) Now, i want to make the reverse, when it is plugged, it start automaticaly any idea ?

I tried to make a program using "wake up", didnt work

Comment: You've provided few details; you mention a release (20.04) but not what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product you're using. Is this a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server install?? a Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop install?? or another 20.04 install??  If I was wanting to do what you wanted, I'd just create an entry in the *autostart* queue to have it play... but your install may differ to mine given I don't know what 20.04 product you're actually using, so adjust for your *unstated* product.

Comment: This needs to be supported by BIOS, not Ubuntu